# Using INDIRECT in cell validity

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I have a spreadsheet contain 3 sheets. I want to set validity of column E of the first sheet based on text in the column D.

The relation between these two columns are placed in the second sheet as two columns: column A contains texts (which are validation values for column D in the first sheet) and column B contain ranges like "Sheet3.A1:A100" which I would like to set them for cell range validation of column E of the first sheet.

#### Sheet 1: (Both columns have Cell Range Validation)

```
|    D    |        E        |
|---------|-----------------|
| Dev1    | Spec1 of Dev1   |
| Dev1    | Spec2 of Dev1   |
| Dev2    | Spec2 of Dev2   |
```

#### Sheet 2:

```
|    A    |        B        |
|---------|-----------------|
| Dev1    | Sheet3.A1:A100  |
| Dev2    | Sheet3.B1:B100  |
```

#### Sheet 3:

```
|        A        |        B        |
|-----------------|-----------------|
| Spec1 of Dev1   | Spec1 of Dev2   |
| Spec2 of Dev1   | Spec2 of Dev2   |
```

---

#### Now The Problem

I wrote the following formula for **Cell Range Validation** of column E of the first sheet, but it seems not work!

```
INDIRECT(VLOOKUP(INDIRECT("D" & ROW()),Sheet2.A1:B100,2,0))
```

The result of this formula is something like this for column E:

```
Spec1 of Dev1    <-- Correct
#Value!          <-- What's this?
#Value!
#Value!
...
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: I believe the problem is that to work this way the INDIRECT function needs to be an array function.  In a cell you would type the formula then press Ctrl + Shift + Enter to set the formula as an array.  In the Data Validity form I'm not aware of any way to enter the formula as an array.

Answer (score 0):

Use "Sheet2.$A$1:$B$100" instead of "Sheet2.A1:B100"

You need to make the reference absolute, otherwise the lower lines look in a different range (like Sheet2.A2:B101, Sheet2.A3:B102, etc.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it does not work unfortunately. No changes happened!